# Is it safe to restart virtual disk service?

Tags: services, windows-services

Will it cause any problems to restart virtual disk service? What does it do?

We have a USB hard drive that does not appear in my computer or disk manager, but does appear in device manager.  My thought is that restarting the virtual disk manager would help. Its description is "Provides management services for disks, volumes, file systems, and storage arrays."

Comment: I would eject/unmount the disk before you doing anything with the service.

Comment: Already tried dismounting the drive and plugging it back in and it still doesn't appear as a drive letter.  When I restart the computer it shows a drive letter but then when i swap HD's for the next nights backup i get the same problem with it not showing up with a drive letter.